# Assembly language strange error

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm new to assembly language and I'm getting a strange error. The program is supposed to display the 4 least significant bits of the integer the user entered. It works for numbers bigger than 8, but for numbers less than or equal to 8 it outputs the digit where the ones should be. For 8 it outputs 8000 instead of 1000, and for five it outputs 0401. I don't understand why, can anyone help?

```
        .data
inPrompt:   .asciiz "Enter an integer: "
outLab:     .asciiz "Least significant 4 bits of int entered are "
############################ code segment ################################
        .text
        .globl main
main:
        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, inPrompt        
        syscall                   # print input prompt

        li $v0, 5
        syscall                   # read input integer

        move $t0, $v0

        li $v0, 4
        la $a0, outLab        
        syscall

        li $v0, 1

        andi $a0, $t0, 8               
                syscall

        andi $a0, $t0, 4             
                syscall

        andi $a0, $t0, 2             
                syscall

        andi $a0, $t0, 1        
                syscall
          ##########################################################

                li $v0, 10               # exit
                syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are effectively computing and printing the *additive decomposition of the number* (in factors of powers of two) rather than its bits.

Simply put, for example for the "bit 4"
    `andi $a0, $t0, 4`  
will result in storing in register `A0`...
  - ..the value `4` if the value in register `T0` has an additive factor of 4 (e.g. 4, 5, 6, 7, 12, 13 etc.)
and
 - ... the value 0 if the value in `T0` doesn't have an additive factor of 4 (e.g. 0, 1, 2, 3, 8, 9, 10 etc.).

This explains why for `5` you get  `0401`  since `5 is 4 + 1` or more precisely, `5 is 0 * 8 + 4 + 0 * 2 + 1`

What you need to do is *one of* two things:

- Test if the result of the `andi` operation result is non-zero, and in that case, load 1 into $a0 before calling syscall
  or
- [bitwise] shift the result of `andi` operation by the corresponding number of bits (3 times when testing for the "8 bit", twice when testing the "4 bit" and once when testing the "2 bit")

The first suggestion would result in something like the following, in lieu of the 'andi + syscall' groups:

```
            andi $a0, $t0, 4
            blez $a0, outBit4  # bit is zero output integer value 0
            li $a0, 1          # bit is one  ouptut integer value 1 (repl 4 by 1)
  outBit4:  syscall
```

**Edit**:
**On keeping the program under 16 LoC...**  (BTW, this requirement and other hints indicate `homework` so I'll provide the general ideas rather than giving out the code)
There are a couple of ways of shortening the code but the 16 LoC requirement is a bit tough considering that 9 lines are used the setup: prompting user for input, getting input and saving it, and outputting the start of the answer...

The most common approach is to use one (or several nested) loop(s).  In this instance a single loop would suffice, essentially you need to repeat 4 times almost the same thing, so at the expense of adding a few LoCs to manage the loop itself (i.e. increment parameters and detect end of loop condition), you can write a snippet to handle a single unit of work, in a parametrized fashion, and have this logic inside the loop.

A slightly related approach is to use subroutine(s), whereby the repeated logic in written in a subroutine which can then be called multiple times, passing different arguments to achieve parametrized behavior.

I mentioned the above because they are very commonly used in assembly language and indeed with programming-at-large.  However, with the current 'andi-based` logic neither of these approaches would bring things under 16 LoC, I'm afraid.  You may need to use a loop structure *and* a bit-shift logic.

Comment: I had tried to implement your first suggestion but I am only allowed to use 16 lines of code and I couldn't manage it. Because if it is zero, I need to output that two, so I would need two branches right? For your second suggestion, do you mean sll or sra?

Comment: @EmilyAnnHall  a) If it is 0 it also output given the suggested snippet; no need for `else`: in both case we ouput, the only difference is that if zero we skip over the setting value to 1.  b) Second suggestion implies `SRL` i.e. shift-right logical (although since we have only positive value, `SRA` would have same effect)  c) as to keeping things under 16 lines, see edit.

Comment: Your second suggestion totally worked! You're amazing, I really appreciate your help.